# A basic query about Thread & join usage c#

Tags: c#, multithreading

some time i used thread in my program but i never use join(). i got something about join() like below

```
Join will stop the current running thread and let the "Join" thread runs until it finishes.

static void Main()
{
  Thread t = new Thread (Go);
  t.Start();
  t.Join();
  Console.WriteLine ("Thread t has ended!");
}

static void Go()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) Console.Write ("y");
}
```

from the above code i just do not understand what kind of important role the join() is playing here. please discuss about the join usage.

if possible give me a small realistic code for join() as a result i can understand the good use of join().

also guide me join() can be use in multi threaded environment. thanks

Comment: The example code you posted is fine. Have you executed the code or used a debugger?

Comment: 'some time i used thread in my program but i never use join()' - good, keep it up :)

Comment: `t.Join()` basically means `wait here until t has finished his work`. This is necessary especially if you need to get the result of a thread **before** you can proceed. For example, you might want to finish **all** data processing, **before** actually saving the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you remove t.Join() from your code application it will end execution before you can be certain that Go() method executed.

Join is very useful if you have got 2 or more methods that can be executed at the same time but all of them need to finalize, before you can execute a method that depends on them.

Please look at below code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(Method1);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(Method2);
        t1.Start();
        t2.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Both methods are executed independently now");
        t1.Join(); // wait for thread 1 to complete
        t2.Join(); // wait for thread 2 to complete
        Console.WriteLine("both methods have completed");
        Method3(); // using results from thread 1 and thread 2 we can execute  method3 that can use results from Method1 and Method2

        }
```

Comment: if i need to run Method1 & Method2 simultaneously then what i need to write code but dead lock should not happen.

Comment: @Thomas if Method1 and Method2 are accessing the same data (objects, variables etc) you will need to synchronise access to that data. Please read this link (lock keyword) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms173179(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 4):

Using the code you posted as an example, if it were written like this:

```
static void Main()
{
  Thread t = new Thread (Go);
  t.Start();
  Console.WriteLine ("Thread t has ended!");
}

static void Go()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) Console.Write ("y");
}
```

your output would be something along the lines of:

yyy
Thread t has ended!yyyyyyy

meaning `Go()` runs simultaneously with `Console.WriteLine ("Thread t has ended!");`

By adding t.join(), you wait till your thread is finished before continuing. This is useful if you only want a section of your code to run simultaneously with a thread.

Comment: Well, the output from `Go` must not necessarily be complete, as the program might be over before...

Comment: so u mean t.join() will make wait the main thread until another thread ended....am i right?

Comment: @Thomas yes, more or less. `t.Join()` will make the main thread wait until whatever `Thread t` was doing is finished.

Answer (score 2):

Blocks the calling thread until the termination of a thread.

Note : You can also blocks the calling thread until a thread terminates or the specified time elapses, while continuing to run the standard COM and SendMessage pumping.
Supported by the. NET Compact Framework.

link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.threading.thread.join(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Consider some game example.

```
static void Main()
{
  Thread t = new Thread (LoadMenu);
  t.Start();
  Showadvertisement();
  t.Join();
  ShowMenu();
}

static void LoadMenu()
{
    //loads menu from disk, unzip textures, online update check.
}

static void Showadvertisement()
{
    //Show the big nvidia/your company logo fro 5 seconds
}

static void ShowMenu()
{
   //everithing is already loaded. 
}
```

The point is you can make multiple things in two threads, but at one point you should synchronize them and be sure, that everything allready completed

Answer (score 0):

.Join() call waits until the thread ends. I mean this call will return when your Go method returns.